# Perform click,swipe,fling similar to GestureDescription below 24?

Tags: android, accessibilityservice, android-gesture, accessibility, accessibility-api

Use case is I need to perform some interaction like click,swipe etc on another app on foreground from my accessibilty service.I am able to achieve this using GestureDescription which was added in Android Noughat. How to achieve this for previous versions? TouchUtils can't be used in production. I did my research before asking but couldn't get a solution. A snippet would be helpful.

Comment: Its not a duplicate "keag" for your kind information.. I dont have view id's nor do intend to use monkey runner as I need it on production app.

Comment: Well my answer on that particular question includes direct information on the subject, for posterity I'll go ahead and submit it as an answer here.